# Access MS SQL Server with public/client connections

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a MS SQL Server 2012 instance installed on a machine at home. I am trying to create a client app using python. How do I enable multiple users to connect to the database simultaneously? I am unable to establish a connection on python via current connection string. Using Ubuntu 14.04 on laptop and Windows Server 2012 on home machine.

The following has been done:

1. Enabled SQL and Windows Authentication
2. Opened ports 1433 and 1434 in Firewall
3. Created an account with noip (xuser.noip.me) for dynamic DNS
4. Installed needed libraries for mssql connection via python

import pyodbc

```
 db = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={X};SERVER=Y;DATABASE=Z;UID=B;PWD=G')
 c = db.cursor()
```

This is the code I used. Is it correct. What information belongs in each variable? At present I have:

X. SQL SERVER

Y. Server Name (my noip.me address)

Z. Name of the database (Name of the database I want to access)

B. User Name

G. Password created in SQL Management Studio

The error is:

pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Have you set up port forwarding on your router?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I have for both port 1433 and 1434 to the servers local ip address (192.x.x.x)